# Add a pop-up layout in Android

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, native, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using this app called Reflect.ly and when you click the 'add' button, a partial screen pop-ups up, now I know that this app is developed bin hybrid but is it possible to do the same in native?

[**Here is the image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIsZf.jpg)

credits: Reflect.ly

Comment: Check this: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beautiful_popup

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DialogFragment.
Checkout the documentation about "Dialog" and use a fragment.